# undefined value returned using jquery and web api

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I changed from searching an ID to searching a name and for some reason the below is returning an undefined value.

```
                var uri = 'http://localhost:11313/api/Mountains?name=';

                function formatItem(item) {
                    return item.Latitude +', '+ item.Longitude;
                }

                function find() {
                    var search = $('#MountID').val();
                    $.getJSON(uri + search)
                        .done(function (data) {
                            $('#mountain').text(formatItem(data));
                        })
                        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                            $('#mountain').text('Error: ' + err);
                        });
                }
```

This however works fine?

```
                var uri = 'http://localhost:11313/api/Mountains'; //changed

                function formatItem(item) {
                    return item.Latitude +', '+ item.Longitude;
                }

                function find() {
                    var search = $('#MountID').val();
                    $.getJSON(uri + '/' + search) //changed
                        .done(function (data) {
                            $('#mountain').text(formatItem(data));
                        })
                        .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
                            $('#mountain').text('Error: ' + err);
                        });
                }
```

Is there a reason this path works `var uri = 'http://localhost:11313/api/Mountains';` and this does not `var uri = 'http://localhost:11313/api/Mountains?name=';`?

I can access `var uri = 'http://localhost:11313/api/Mountains?name=';` with a name on the end from my browser just fine?

```
<Mountain>
<Height_ft>2953</Height_ft>
<Height_m>900</Height_m>
<ID>c21</ID>
<Latitude>57.073142</Latitude>
<Longitude>-3.3310457</Longitude>
<Name>Culardoch</Name>
<humidity>0.42</humidity>
<snowCover>1.84</snowCover>
<temperature>66</temperature>
</Mountain>
```

I get a status 200 ok and I get a respone from the actual search when I click the button:
[image]

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(Mountain))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetMountain(string id)
    {
        Mountain mountain = db.Mountains.Find(id);
        if (mountain == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(mountain);
    }


    public IQueryable<Mountain> GetMountainByName(string name)
    {
        return db.Mountains.Where(n => string.Equals(n.Name, name));
    }
```

Comment: if you view the network tab in your browser debug tools, what does the outgoing request look like?  Are you expecting something like: `localhost:11313/api/mountains?name=search` ?

Comment: The outgoing request looks ok `http://localhost:11313/api/Mountains?name=Culardoch` returns a status 200 ok. Still says `undefined, undefined` tho?

Comment: What is in `data`?

Comment: Lat and long coordinates.

Comment: so in browser debug tools, network tab, click the api request, click the 'response' tab... what does the data look like?

Comment: @Delosdos the data is the exact same response as with using the ID to search with. I can search the name fine and get a response but still scratching my head why its undefined for the two different paths?

Comment: Can you say what's happening in the server-side? Maybe we can solve that there

Comment: Updated but like I said I get the response so its definately a issue with the jquery. One path is accepted and one is not.

Comment: @GarrithGraham I think you should use the `$.ajax` method, then parse the json manually using `JSON.parse`.

Comment: I have noticed that the name search creates an 0: Object at the beginning and the ID search returns no object.

Comment: in your response, you get an array.. were you expecting one?  e.g. data[0]

Comment: @GarrithGraham I noticed too, it's a array. But I wasn't sure, so... I solved to say nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to index the `data` array (I know that's obvious, but I seen op question in the comments) using `[` and `]`, declaring the number `0`:

E.g:

```
data = data[0];
```

Do that inside your `done` function, then it's done. Like so:

```
                $.getJSON(uri + search)
                    .done(function (data) {
                        data = data[0];
                        $('#mountain').text(formatItem(data));
                    })
```

(yeah, I thought you had solved it)

Comment: @GarrithGraham Glad of help !